# Portfolio rebalancing with PerformanceAnalytics

Tags: r, performanceanalytics

I am trying to use PerformanceAnalytics to backtest some portfolio performance with daily rebalancing. A dummy example is below:

```
ret     <- xts(matrix(rnorm(20, 0, 0.01), nrow = 10), as.Date(1:10))
weights <- runif(10)
weights <- xts(cbind(weights, 1 - weights), as.Date(1:10))

names(ret) <- c('a', 'b')
names(weights) <- names(ret)

Return.rebalancing(ret, weights)
```

However, the code above gives the following error:

`Error in '[.xts'(result, 2:length(result)) : subscript out of bounds`

What am I missing?

Comment: Already reported: [R-SIG-Finance Return.rebalancing and rebalancing on consecutive days](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-finance/2013q1/011387.html) and fixed in [revision 2330](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/PerformanceAnalytics/R/Return.portfolio.R?root=returnanalytics&r1=2287&r2=2330) on R-Forge.

Comment: Thanks. I installed the latest version and it works.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: For some reason Return.rebalancing is surprisingly slow. Using the code above for 2000 days takes 4.5 seconds on a very fast computer, while using multiplication on the coredata takes almost no time. Is this expected?